# Get all queues of an exchange in RabbitMQ

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

Using RabbitMQ.Client, I wonder how these are possible:

1. Get all queues names?
2. To what exchange a queue is bound?
3. How to get all queues which are bound to an exchange?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but you can find all this information using [RabbitMQ Management HTTP API](https://rabbitmq.com/management.html#http-api)

You have to enable the [rabbtimq management plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html), using:

> rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management

After that you can use c# for execute HTTP calls.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just note that the API documentation link is a little old. I check this one: http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-management/raw-file/rabbitmq_v3_3_4/priv/www/api/index.html

Comment: Now, my question is how fast and reliable is this HTTP API? And why aren't those functionalities available in the client libraries?

Comment: ops.. I edited the answer. Those functionals are not provider by default on AMQP protocol. The management plug-in is a stable and enough fast, you should make some test.

Comment: First link in answer is dead - *"This site can’t be reached 
- DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN"*.