# Count of consumers in RabbitMQ (with exchange)

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, amqp

If I don't use exchange in RabbitMQ, I can get count of consumers:

```
channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "Sellers",
                     durable: false,
                     exclusive: false,
                     autoDelete: false,
                     arguments: null);

int sellersCount = channel.ConsumerCount("Sellers");
```

How can I detect count of consumers with exchange:

```
channel.ExchangeDeclare(exchange: "Shop",
                        type: "direct");

channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "Shop",
                     routingKey: "Sellers",
                     basicProperties: null,
                     body: body1);

channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "Shop",
                     routingKey: "Clients",
                     basicProperties: null,
                     body: body2);

int sellersCount = ???
int clientsCount = ???
```

Comment: There is no such thing as number of consumers for exchange. Exchange routes messages to one or more queues.

Comment: Can I get queues objects from exchange? I can get count of consumers by queue name. But I don't know how can I get queue names from exchange

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do that via amqp protocol itself. However there is a management plugin to rabbitmq, and that plugin has http api. With that api you _might_ be able to get queues bound to certain exchange at current moment. Though I must admit that the fact you need to do that might indicate some flaw in your design, because you should never need to do that. Can you clarify the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I need to know the number of sellers. If number of sellers is equal 0, I display for clients: "No sellers online".

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on [Evk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5311735/evk)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43953137/count-of-consumers-in-rabbitmq-with-exchange#comment74941040_43953137), here's the [RabbitMQ Management HTTP API documentation](https://rawcdn.githack.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/rabbitmq_v3_6_9/priv/www/api/index.html). Try `GET /api/exchanges/vhost/name/bindings/source`:

> A list of all bindings in which a given exchange is the source.

Note there are a [couple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21286370/1062614) [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27909730/1062614) answers to touch on this solution as well.